# Redraw a UserForm in VBA

Tags: vba, userform, redraw

I have a userform in VBA and I'd like to redraw/update it in the middle of a method.

When the method is called on button click, the function is as below:

```
UsrForm.Field1.Value = ""
UsrForm.Field2.Value = ""
UsrForm.Label1.Caption = "LOADING..."

/*Processing occurs*/

UsrForm.Field1.Value = val1
UsrForm.Field2.Value = val2
UsrForm.Label1.Caption = "DONE"
```

However, the update to the form visible only occurs when the method is completed. I get val1, val2, and "DONE" but not the "LOADING..." message. Is there a way to redraw in the middle of the method?

Comment: Try `DoEvents` or `Me.Repaint` after the loading message

Comment: @z̍̄̒ͪ̚ Repaint worked great. Submit as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `UsrForm.Repaint` after the loading message:

```
UsrForm.Field1.Value = ""
UsrForm.Field2.Value = ""
UsrForm.Label1.Caption = "LOADING..."
UsrForm.Repaint
'...
```