# Application.wait in userform -duplicate-

Tags: vba, userform

so I am trying to 'animate' a userform so that the text in a label changes over time. here is a sample of my code (it's run upon clicking a button in the userform):

```
Label2.Caption = "hello"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Label2.Caption = "10"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Label2.Caption = "9"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Label2.Caption = "8"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Label2.Caption = "7"
```

This should open with hello, then count from 10 to 7 with 1-second intervals.

When I run the code, the label changes to hello, then freezes for about 30 seconds, then, shows the last number. this problem does not happen if I step through the code with the debugger.

I've shown that Application.wait works on its own with this code (in a normal sub):

```
cells(1,1) = "hi"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
cells(1,1) = "bye"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
cells(1,1) = "hi"
```

how do I fix this and why is it broken?

EDIT:
This question is a duplicate. See this [question](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/23545521/redraw-a-userform-in-vba)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545521/redraw-a-userform-in-vba

Comment: Please, try `DoEvents`. Or `Me.Repaint`.

Comment: Fixed it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `.Repaint` between changes. so my new code is:

```
Label2.Caption = "hello"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Label2.Caption = "10"
myForum.Repaint

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Label2.Caption = "9"
myForum.Repaint

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Label2.Caption = "8"
myForum.Repaint

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Label2.Caption = "7"
myForum.Repaint
```